# Small Files Upload in HTML, but larger ones do not

Tags: php, html, forms, wamp, xls

I am uploading an excel file using

```
  <form action="import.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Before I do anything, I give it  a quick:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

This works fine on a reduced version of the excel file (100 rows) but the full version (4000 rows) simply returns null with no errors, etc.

```
 post_max_size = 30M
 upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

Var_Dump returns:

```
 array (size=0)
      empty
```

Comment: I have seen this as well, in my searching, but changing these settings in Apache and PHP made no difference.

Comment: Not sure why 5 people marked it as a duplicate, the problem is different than the one linked.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your project if there is something like that :

```
ini_set('post_max_size', 'SOME_VALUE');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', 'SOME_VALUE');
```

If you have included libraries in your project, sometimes they initialize some php values.